# Python - Open image in binary mode with a URL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, google-cloud-vision

I have a snippet that reads my images locally (returns binary), i.e:

```
image = 'car.jpg'
with open(image, 'rb') as image_file:
    content = image_file.read()
```

I'm trying to recreate the same but with images that are hosted on the internet, I have tried with the following but I've had no luck.

```
from urllib.request import  urlopen
from PIL import Image
import io

url = 'https://somewebsite.com/fm-01/car.jpg'

image = urlopen(url)
image_file = io.BytesIO(image.read())
im = Image.open(image_file)
im = im.tobytes()
```

**EDIT ...**

Same exact image, one on google cloud storage and the other one locally.
They have different bytes when opening them.

```
with open('car.jpg','rb') as image_file:
    content = image_file.read()
    print(len(content))
```

size : 234712

```
url = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/fm-01/car.jpg'
img = Image.open(urlopen(url))
image = img.tobytes()
print(len(image))
```

size : 1077600

Answer (score 1):

It is simple as:

```py
from urllib.request import urlopen

url = 'https://somewebsite.com/fm-01/car.jpg'

img = urlopen(url).read()
```

Comment: it returns a "<class 'PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile'>", I need it in binary.

Comment: I can't get what you really want to achieve. If you need bytes of file hosted in internet you don't need PIL at all `b = urlopen(url).read()`

Comment: yikes, can't believe I missed that! ha..! thank you so much.

Comment: @gm_will *"in binary"* is not a very good description! Do you mean you need the bytes of the JPEG-encoded file *"as-is"* as they appear on disk with the camera model, make and GPS all encoded in, or do you mean you need the binary representation of the pixels, i.e. `0xff 0x00 0x00...` if the first pixel is red.

Comment: I basically needed to “read” the image, as in using python built-in function open() with ‘rb’, read binary mode. The snippet you sent worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You have not understood the comment I made explaining exactly this under Mikhail's answer.

The 234,712 bytes is the size of the JPEG-encoded data in the disk file - it includes the image height, width, date, GPS coordinates, camera manufacturer and the all the pixels of the image DCT-compressed into a JPEG.

The 1,077,600 bytes is the size of the array you will need to create in memory to hold the uncompressed red, green and blue pixels in, say 898x400 pixels at 3 bytes (1 red, 1 green and 1 blue) per pixel.

```
898 * 400 * 3 = 1077600
```